# Python - Parsing Conundrum

Tags: python, parsing, csv

I have searched high and low for a resolution to this situation, and tested a few different methods, but I haven't had any luck thus far. Basically, I have a file with data in the following format that I need to convert into a CSV:

```
(previously known as CyberWay Pte Ltd)
0 2019
01.com
0 1975
1 TRAVEL.COM
0 228
1&1 Internet
97 606
1&1 Internet AG
0 1347
1-800-HOSTING
0 8
1Velocity
0 28
1st Class Internet Solutions
0 375
2iC Systems
0 192
```

I've tried using re.sub and replacing the whitespace between the numbers on every other line with a comma, but haven't had any success so far. I admit that I normally parse *from* CSVs, so raw text has been a bit of a challenge for me. I would need to maintain the string formats that are above each respective set of numbers.

I'd prefer the CSV to be formatted as such:

```
foo bar
0,8
foo bar
0,9
foo bar
0,10
foo bar
0,11
```

There's about 50,000 entries, so manually editing this would take an obscene amount of time.

If anyone has any suggestions, I'd be most grateful.

Thank you very much.

Comment: So it's simply that you want a comma instead of a space between the two entries on every other line?

Comment: The output format you describe isn't a "real" CSV, since the lines have different numbers of elements.  Reading this with a CSV reader is likely to produce strange results or errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have correctly understood your requirement, you need a strip() on all lines and a split based on whitespace on even lines (lines starting from 1):

```
import re

fp = open("csv.txt", "r")
while True:
    line = fp.readline()
    if '' == line:
            break
    line    = line.strip()
    fields  = re.split("\s+", fp.readline().strip())
    print "\"%s\",%s,%s" % ( line, fields[0], fields[1] )
fp.close()
```

The output is a CSV (you might need to escape quotes if they occur in your input):

```
"Content of odd line",Number1,Number2
```

I do not understand the 'foo,bar' you place as header on your example's odd lines, though.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to replace whitespace with comma, you can just do:

```
line = ','.join(line.split())
```

You'll have to do this only on every other line, but from your question it sounds like you already figured out how to work with every other line.